# Not Show alert in Ajax call with MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc 4 controller method to get some data by using AJAX method. unfortunately its not working. I have do some thing in to success and error area. I need to get what is the error in this code.

Ajax Method :

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var country = $('#cnname').val();
        var customerID = $('#CustomerId').val();
        if (country == "United Kingdom") {
            if (800 <= $('#SrcAmt').val() < 2000) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/CustomerIdentity/IdentityList',
                    data: { 'customerId': customerId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('ok');
                    },
                    error: function (event) {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

MVC Controller :

```
public JsonResult IdentityList(int customerId)
        {
            var customeridentity = db.CustomerIdentity.Include(c => c.Customer).Include(c => c.CountryIssued)
                .Where(item => item.CustomerId == customerId);
            if (customeridentity.Count() > 0)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check what error you are getting in console

Comment: Its nothing to show.. Method Hit after }); in the ajax method. How to track the success and error

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the problem that you are facing before. There are probably 3 kinds of problems:

**1. Logical Error**
Did you check your code completely, and have you debugged it at all? Did you find unexpected output?
If there is none then move to second error.

**2. Type of HTTP Method**
I recommend that you use `POST` rather than `GET`, because as I know, you send some data to the ASP WebMethod.

**3. Path of ASPX File**
Try to remove backslash (`/`) as the first character of `/CustomerIdentity/IdentityList`, so it should be `CustomerIdentity/IdentityList`

The weird case is when your browser still contains your previous javascript code, try to run your code using private browsing tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using @Url.Action("action,"controller") to get the rigth path of your controller action, its chance that action url is wrong

In url property of Ajax call do like this:

url: `Url.Action("action,"controller")`